# Is COM object redirection via "TreatAs" supported by WinCE 5.0 and above?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, windows-ce

If not, is there a way to obtain equivalent functionality? We want to provide a new COM component as a drop-in replacement for a panel who's vendor can change things in the registry, but not their client code.

Answer (score 1):

We were never able to get "TreatAs" to work. The best workaround was to change the legacy HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID default value to the class ID of the new server.

This allowed the legacy client to continue to use the existing PROGID, yet invoke the new COM server.